# PowerQuery - List.PositionOf() During Aggregation based on secondary field

Tags: excel, powerquery

**Current Formula:**
= Table.AggregateTableColumn(#"GroupedRows", "Count", {{"domTotal", each List.PositionOf("domTotal", "bestSeason"), "bestSeasonIndex"}})

**Image of the Query:** https://i.stack.imgur.com/OFutG.jpg

I grouped Table Rows by a shared ID. Each row now has a field `[bestSeason]` and a Table `[Count]`. I am trying to aggregate the Table `[Count]` by the field `[domTotal]`.  Rather than doing a traditional Aggregation like `List.Max` I want to access the List with `List.PositionOf()` to find what the index is where the field `domTotal=bestSeason`.

Is this possible within an Aggregation?

Comment: Yes. If I understand you correctly, it should be possible to get that result. If not within the Aggregation, then in a separate column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this issue by accessing the table directly via adding custom columns rather than during the aggregation step.  It turned out to be extremely slow so I switched to JavaScript for the grouping aggregation.